# Signal Handling C programming on ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, signals

While I sending `kill -9` command to a program on ubuntu , I want to close other running processes before the program closes.I am trying this with c programming . Could it be something like this? How can I say program if you get KILL command you should do something?

Comment: If you read [the `signal(7)` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) you will see that `SIGKILL` can not be caught, blocked or ignored. So you can't use it in your program.

Comment: In the general case, there are *many* tutorials on how to catch signals in ones program if you just search a little.

Comment: I search but I didn' t come across that page. I am new to signal handling. Thank you I will read that page

Comment: It might help to learn what `SIGKILL` is for and think about it. "I search but I didn' t come across that page" - looks like you first should take a "how to search" course.

Comment: You are right . Now I took that course thanks

Comment: Hardly. Anyway, you have an XY problem. **Why** do you think you want to catch it? Why do you expect SIGKILL to be sent during normal operation?

Comment: I want to the application, if killed, terminates gracefully.

Comment: `I want to the application, if killed, terminates gracefully.` - Then prepare your application to `kill`, which sends SIGINT, not to `kill -9`. Unlike to SIGKILL, SIGINT signal can be catched, and you can implement all logic you need. Command `kill -9` normally is used when application does not respond to simple `kill`.

Comment: I understood thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the POSIX standard <signal.h> documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html):

> ...
>
> The following signals shall be supported on all implementations
>   (default actions are explained below the table):
>
> ```
> Signal   Default Action  Description
> ....
> SIGKILL  T               Kill (cannot be caught or ignored).
> ```

Note well the "cannot be caught or ignored".

Your process never "sees" `SIGKILL` as the OS just kills the process without any notice.

Comment: I don't understand . ıf my program running and  get signal then terminated how can avoid that problem?

Comment: @Melo: **You can't** That's the idea of `SIGKILL`.

Comment: This signal is the signal of last resort. The purpose is to be able to kill a process even if it has signal handlers that don't exit the process. That's why you're not allowed to catch it, that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: Okey I understand better now. I just wondered if such a question would be possible. thank you

Comment: That's why you should use `kill -TERM` first. `SIGTERM` can be caught to allow a clean shutdown.